# config alpine's proxy in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I use mvn clean package docker:build to invoke dockerfile(docker version 18.03.1-ce ) in machine B:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN  apk update && apk upgrade && apk add netcat-openbsd && apk add curl
```

it turns out:

```
Step 2/8 : RUN  apk update && apk upgrade && apk add netcat-openbsd && apk add curl

     ---> Running in 89c9b97b9d75
    fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
    fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
    ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main: temporary error (try again later)
    WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.70c88391.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

I figure out it's network problem,machine B access internet by machine A,I have tried add "dns" in /etc/docker/daemon.json, "httpProxy" in ~/.docker/config.json , now I success in running:

```
`docker run -it cc2179b8f042`
apk update
```

but when I come back to use maven invoking dockfile ,it doesn't work. So how can I make dockfile work and tell me any difference between this two case.

Comment: try passing a build-argument `http_proxy` with correct value.

Comment: I use mvn clean package  docker:build  -Ddocker.buildArg.http_proxy=xx ,still not work. I fix it by adding "ENV http_proxy xx" in dockfile for now .

Comment: You can try setting this in pom.xml  , Take a look at https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/pull/41

Comment: I use old docker-maven-plugin 1.1.1 and put a issue in github .  I will check dockerfile-maven later.

Answer (score 9):

---

It seems like you're required to set `http_proxy` in your Dockerfile. If you do (e.g. for a specific, temporary reason - say you're building your container behind a corporate proxy) and subsequently don't need it anymore I'd suggest something like the following:

```
RUN export \
  http_proxy="http://some.custom.proxy:8080/” \
  https_proxy="https://some.custom.proxy:8080/" \
  \
  && < E.G. pip install requirements.txt> \
  \
  && unset http_proxy https_proxy
```

You can also use a more permanent solution in your Dockerfile by invoking `ENV`, but be aware that these are persisted and can lead to problems further down the road if you push/deploy your images somewhere else - [Reference](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#env).

Comment: Is there any config file so that we can specify proxy in it?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're aiming at, but you can configure a proxy for Docker, yes. The config file would be in `~/.docker/config.json` - check [this doc](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/). You can also edit this in your Docker preferences if you use e.g. Docker for Mac

Comment: Hey @heldic Thanks for your comment.
I was aiming for how to use/set proxy to build dockerfile. Using that proxy I supposed to download packages. I have set proxy as environment variable in docker file, but while building docker file it shows proxy error 'Permission denied' so is it any other way or its an issue with proxy server?

Answer (score 1):

You can set proxy using high case environment variables.

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://<your proxy ip>:<your proxy port>"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "http://<your proxy ip>:<your proxy port>"
RUN apk add --no-cache python2
```

I hope, this will helps.